# Auth::logout() on missing remember_token database field

Tags: php, laravel-4

I was simply trying to log out admin user from the Dashboard while I used this code for doing it:

Routes.php

```
Route::get('logout',array('uses'=>'AuthController@LogOut'));
```

AuthController.php

```
class AuthController extends Controller{

   public function LogOut(){

    Auth::logout();
    return Redirect::to('login');
   }
}
```

while it is giving me such error for log out

[image: Erro]

as i don't have such field in Database, and also it is not added to Database while Migration also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is most likely occurring because the `remember_token` field is required by the `Auth` to be present in the `users` table. So you should add a `remember_token` field (likely a string field) in your `users` migration table and migrate it. Then, you should create a user, log in the user and then try logging out. Hopefully, doing this will solve your problem.

Comment: But it didn't give an error while Loging IN, and it is trying to update it so , why is doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've run an update with composer recently and have upgraded the Laravel core. You'll need to perform a few steps to upgrade to the newest Laravel version as documented in the Laravel upgrade info here: http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade#upgrade-4.1.26

> Laravel 4.1.26 introduces security improvements for "remember me"
>   cookies...change requires the addition of a new remember_token
>   column to your users (or equivalent) database table.

You'll also need to update your `User` class with these methods if you're using Eloquent:

```
public function getRememberToken()
{
    return $this->remember_token;
}

public function setRememberToken($value)
{
    $this->remember_token = $value;
}

public function getRememberTokenName()
{
    return 'remember_token';
}
```